# wermgr.exe event in security log right before system freeze -- any way to get more info?

Tags: freeze, windows-server-2012

We have a system that has been hanging inexplicably and without much to go on in the following logs:
Application Log,
System Log,
Security Log,
IIS Logs,
Custom Application Logs.

Everything just freezes up without leaving much evidence as to the cause.  I did notice in the security log one of the last entries was for wermgr.exe.  I realize this is the symptom of the problem not the cause -- but what I am curious about is if there is any way to get more information out of that error manager?  Is there a log file somewhere or dump directory that may have more clues?  There is nothing valuable to go on (or if there is I am missing it) prior to the issue occurring in any other log.  Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: Does the keyboard work when the system is frozen? If yes you can force a kernel dump https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/969028

Comment: If existing logs don't provide sufficient details, you might need to generate more logs.  For instance, create logs that show the name of every process that is running, every 2 minutes.  Also show memory usage, as often programs that do bad things may increase in activity before a freeze occurs.

Comment: Yes very good advice thank you both.  We've added Sysmon to the server and are monitoring.